# filterSearch, search in all columns

Tags: magento2, filter

Faced the problem that filterSearch does not search for all columns in the table ,but search only works in one column in the table grid.

I installed full text in database columns

My code filterSearch

```
<filterSearch name="fulltext" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/search/search</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">magento_retailmanager_post_listing.magento_retailmanager_post_listing_data_source</item>
                <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">magento_retailmanager_post_listing.magento_retailmanager_post_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">magento_retailmanager_post_listing.magento_retailmanager_post_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filterSearch>
```

Example code created column on UI component

```
 <column name="model">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="width" xsi:type="string">150px</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">model</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

And is it possible to search for information by type LIKE ?
And is it possible to search for digital data in the table?

Answer (score 5):

To make full text search or keyword search of admin grid you need to make or add index of the table

```
$connection->addIndex(
                    'your table name', //table name
                    'index',    // index name
                    [
                        'field or your column name'   // field or column name which is needed for searching enter all columns to be searched 
                    ],
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT //type of index
                );
```

you can write this code in your install schema or in upgrade schema

Then add this line in your UI component xml file

```
 <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
```

this line you can add in this way

```
<listingToolbarname="listing_top">
<columnsControls ="columns_control"/>
 <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
</listingToolbarname/>
```

Hope this will help you !! Happy Coding :)